# Proof that $(a,b)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an open set

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

To prove $(a,b)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ using the definition of an open set, we will show that for each $c \in (a,b)$, a neighborhood $N_{\epsilon}(c)$ centered at $c$ exists, such that $N_{\epsilon}(c) \subseteq (a,b)$.

Let $c \in (a,b)$ and choose $\epsilon = \min\{c-a,b-c\}$. It is clear that $\epsilon > 0$, so construct the neighborhood $N_{\epsilon}(c) = (c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon)$.

To prove that $N_{\epsilon}(c) \subseteq (a,b)$, let $y \in N_{\epsilon}(c)$. Then $|y-c| < \epsilon$, so that

$$a-c \leq -\epsilon < y-c < \epsilon \leq b-c $$

Adding $c$ to the inequality renders $a < y < b$ and $y \in (a,b)$. It follows that every point in $(a,b)$ is an interior point. Hence, (a,b) is an open set.

This proof seems valid, but I want to to be sure.

Comment: It's valid.  That is precisely how to do it.

Comment: Actually you could have done it slightly simpler.  After you construct (c-e, c + e).  Don't bother selecting a y.  Just note.  c+e <= b and a <= c - e and, of course, c-e < c+ e so you have b <= c-e < c+e <= a so (c-e, c+e) is subset (a,b).